# In shell scripting, how do I ensure all characters in a variable are passed literally?

Tags: shell, escaping

Say I have this command:

```
printf $text | perl program.pl
```

How do I guarantee that everything in the $text variable is literally? For example, if $text contains `hello"\n`, how do I make sure that's exactly what gets passed to program.pl, without the newline or quotation mark (or any conceivable character) being interpreted as a special character?

Comment: Do you want things to be escaped, or do you want them to be passed literally? You say you want `"$text"` to be passed literally, but that's *completely different* than passing it escaped -- escaping it would mean adding extra escape characters (allowing it to be read back to its original content if passed through a different shell), which is modification, not preservation.

Comment: By the way, if you wanted to test with your specific use case, that assignment would be best done as `text=$'hello"\n'`, presuming that the `\n` is intended to be a single newline character, as opposed to a backslash character followed by a literal `n`.

Comment: Sorry, I did in fact mean literal, not escaping; I changed the question to reflect that.

Comment: ...by the way -- my question included some bashisms, and I just now noticed that you're tagged `shell` rather than `bash`. Note that `%q` and `%b` are bash extensions, not part of the POSIX standard and so not guaranteed to be available on other shells. (`printf '%s' "$text"`, by contrast, is guaranteed to be supported by any shell compliant with POSIX.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes!

```
printf '%s' "$text" | ...
```

Don't *ever* expand variables unquoted if you care about preserving their contents precisely. Also, don't ever pass a dynamic string as a format variable when you want it to be treated as literal data.

If you want backslash sequences to be interpreted -- for instance, the two-character sequence `\n` to be changed to a single newline -- and your shell is bash, use `printf '%b' "$text"` instead. If you want byte-for-byte accuracy, `%s` is the Right Thing (and works on any POSIX-compliant shell). If you want escaping *for interpretation by another shell* (which would be appropriate if, say, you were passing content as part of a `ssh` command line), then the appropriate format string (for bash only) is `%q`.

Comment: +1 I think you got it right but OP still needs to clarify few things in the question.